# Hash entry sometime is $NULL (error), and sometimes isn't?

Tags: powershell, hash

I have my little 3-sided socket-server. Each server has its own hash with its key-values.

The very first is:

```
$Local = @{ID="Local"; ...}
$RemtA = @{ID="RemtA"; ...}
$RemtB = @{ID="RemtB"; ...}
```

I start for all of the the listeners - no problem.

If now a client wants to connect, I want to add the ID to `$ProgressHead`, which is defined like this:

```
$ProgressHead = "Value-Broadcast, Connected:  "
```

and used in my function to accept a client called with its hash as $h:

```
if ( !$h.Connected ) {
  #Write-Host "$($h.ID) not connected, pending: $($h.listener.Pending())"
  if ( $h.listener.Pending()) {
    $h.client = $h.listener.AcceptTcpClient() # will block here until connection
    $h.stream = $h.client.GetStream();
    $h.writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $h.stream
    $h.writer.AutoFlush = $true
    $h.Connected = $true  
    Write-Host $Global:ProgressHead # fails - empty ??
    Write-Host $h.ID  # prints oh depit it is marked as error
    if ( !$Global:ProgressHead.Contains( $h.ID ) ) { # <= HERE IS THE ERROR ????
      $Global:ProgressHead= "$($Global:ProgressHead)$($h.ID)  "
    }
  }
}
```

The Error message says:

> Can't call a method for an expression which is NULL and $h.ID is underlined

BUT I DO NOT get any error if I start this either in the cmd-console when running `powershell -file ThreeServer.ps1` or within the ISE in debug mode. The ID is written correctly to `$ProgressHead`!

Only if I start this in the Powershell console (`PS C:\...> ./ThreeServer.ps1`) I get this error, but all the other keys in the lines above are valid ONLY `$h.ID` on ONLY the PS-console throws this error?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you start up a fresh PowerShell console and try the script?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it again. I openend a ps console, cd.. to the folder and entered ./ThreeServer.ps1. The listener started and as soon as client wants to connect I get this error. Before that I stopped this script in the cmd.exe, where it was running without problem with 2 clients.

Comment: How/where is `$h` populated`? What is the output when you add `$h | Format-List` right before the line causing the error?

Comment: Even if the error points to $h.ID it is not the problem: $Global:ProgressHead is 'empty'. THIS is the error! All the hash keys in the lines before are valid - only one: $h.ID not and only in the PS-console? Hard to understand. $h is populated and all the keys of $h doe have their expected value..

Comment: The error will probably disappear after you replace `$global:ProgressHead` with `$global:ProcessHead`.

Comment: NO!! This is only my typo on this page - as the SAME script shows an error if started in PS-console, but not if started in ISE-Debugger or cmd.exe! Take this as granted!

Comment: How do you expect anyone to find/fix the issue when even the code in your question contains typos? Not to mention that you didn't provide enough information for anyone to actually reproduce the problem. Fix the typos in your the code sample. Provide the complete, unaltered error message. Make your code sample [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't expect any further response until then.

Comment: 1) The line with my typo was added later and I didn't see it because the fond in the edit-window is so small. 2) My code is minimal and complete as above all the keys of the hash are working (NO ERROR) while only $h.ID fails despite it is the first defined key! 3) I do NOT double post the same problem!! Here the error that was marked by PS.ISE is $h.ID. In my other question I am asking why $global works in the PS-ISE and the DOS-cms.exe but not (I still do knot know, because even you seems not to have any answer!) if the script is started directly in the powershell-console!!